# [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, pdfmake

I'm trying to get the DataURI of an image I passed on my function but it gives me error:

Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function.

**NOTE:** I already installed datauri and trying to copy one of its example

[image: example]

Above image is the example Im trying to use in my method.

```
    <template>
  <section>
    <v-btn color="success" @click="sampleParams">CONVERT TO URI</v-btn>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { sync as DataURI } from "datauri";
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    sampleParams: function() {
      const Datauri = require("datauri");
      let datauri = new Datauri("../python/IDfront.png");

      console.log(datauri.content);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Glancing at the docs, that looks like a node module designed to run on a server. `fs.existsSync` is a method for reading files from your local file system - it won't be defined in your browser (thus the error).

Comment: oh okay, thanks for your reply @DavidWeldon now I know why it gives me error